# Deny user with manager role to edit users with admin role Asp.Net MVC5 Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, authorization, asp.net-identity, asp.net-roles

I have set the app to allow each user to have multiple roles.

```
public class SelectRoleViewModel
{      
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }        
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class EditUser
{
   // other properties

  public List<SelectRoleViewModel> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

now in the Controlles, in the Edit get method I wrote this

```
[CustomAuthorize(Roles = ("Admin,Manager"))]
    public ActionResult Edit(string Id)
    {
        var editUser = GetEditUser(Id);

        bool isAdmin = User.IsInRole("Admin");

        if (!isAdmin)
        {      
            if (editUser.Roles.Exists(x => x.RoleName == "Admin"))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("AccessNotAllowed", "Errors");
            }
        }

        // Here just edit what you want
        return View(editUser);                        
    }

private EditUser GetEditUser(string Id)
    {
        var dbUser = UserManager.Users.Where(x => x.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();
        var currentRoles = dbUser.Roles.Select(x => x.RoleId).ToList();
        var allRoles = _roleManager.Roles.ToList();

        EditUser editUser = new EditUser();
        foreach (var x in allRoles)
        {
            if (currentRoles.Contains(x.Id))
                editUser.Roles.Add(new SelectRoleViewModel { Id = x.Id, RoleName = x.Name, Description = x.Description, Checked = true });
            else
                editUser.Roles.Add(new SelectRoleViewModel { Id = x.Id, RoleName = x.Name, Description = x.Description, Checked = false });
        }

        if (User.IsInRole("Manager"))
        {
            // don't show the admin role to set for users if authenticated user is manager
            var adm = editUser.Roles
                        .Where(x => x.RoleName.Equals("Admin", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        .FirstOrDefault();
            if (adm != null)
            {
                editUser.Roles.Remove(adm);
            }
        }

        editUser.FirstName = dbUser.FirstName;
        editUser.LastName = dbUser.LastName;
        editUser.Email = dbUser.Email;
        editUser.UserName = dbUser.UserName;
        editUser.Id = dbUser.Id;
        return editUser;
    }
```

So, the manager has the right to edit users and to create them, but manager can't create users with admin role.
What I'm trying to do is to deny access for the manager to edit the admin users.
The code I wrote, it takes the whole list of user roles, and since there is an admin role, it always denies access to edit users.
This happens when I comment out this code in the GetEditUser method:

```
if (User.IsInRole("Manager"))
        {
            // don't show the admin role to set for users if authenticated user is manager
            var adm = editUser.Roles
                        .Where(x => x.RoleName.Equals("Admin", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        .FirstOrDefault();
            if (adm != null)
            {
                editUser.Roles.Remove(adm);
            }
        }
```

and with this code (uncommented), it totally removes the admin role from the list, so the manager can still edit the admin users since it don't find the admin role to compare in the if condition.

Can someone help me find a solution to limit manager access for editing admin users and to hide the admin role for managers when creating new user, without changing the users to assign only 1 role? The logic of the app needs to have multiple roles per user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the indicated section of code to the Edit method inside the if(!isAdmin):

```
    if (!isAdmin)
    {      
        if (editUser.Roles.Exists(x => x.RoleName == "Admin" && x.Checked))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("AccessNotAllowed", "Errors");
        }
        var adm = editUser.Roles
                    .Where(x => x.RoleName.Equals("Admin", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    .FirstOrDefault();
        if (adm != null)
        {
            editUser.Roles.Remove(adm);
        }
    }
```

Comment: RemoveAll is not recognizable if there is no Roles. like: editUser.Roles.RemoveAll();

Comment: there is still the problem with the authorization. Hope you can help me about that too... About the part where to hide the admin role for the manager when setting roles for users. I tried your code but I think it didn't work. Well it works actually but with some other issues after. It removes the admin role from the SelectRoleList and it never hit the if where it checks if user to edit has admin role or not

Comment: the problem again with this if `if (editUser.Roles.Exists(x => x.RoleName == "Admin"))` is that with the user it gets the whole RoleList which is stored in SelectRoleViewModel, not just the ones assigned to the user. An if statement must be made where to check if the role admin is checked (true) or not.

Comment: Add a check for x.Checked == true.

Comment: it work for now. hope no problem will appear later. Thank you